# CryptographicException Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, azure, cryptography, azure-sql-database, x509

I am trying to connect to azure to create a sql database dinamically

this is my code

```
 public static class SqlAzureDbHelper
    {
        public static string subscriptionId = SettingsHelper.AzureSubscriptionId;
        public static string base64EncodedCertificate = SettingsHelper.AzureSubscriptionManagementCertificate;

        public static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials()
        {
            return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
        }

        public static void CreateDatabase(string companyName,string nit)
        {
            SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(getCredentials());
            //Server Name is your SQL Azure DataBase server name, for example:da0dt6hrt6 
            client.Databases.Create(SettingsHelper.AzureSqlServer, new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.Models.DatabaseCreateParameters()
            {
                Name = companyName+"-"+nit,
                MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1,
                CollationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
                Edition = "Web"
            });

        }
    }
```

and this is my stack trace

```
 at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] data)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData)
   at Inspinia_MVC5.Data.SqlAzureDbHelper.getCredentials() in C:\Proyectos\SaasAppDemo1\Main\SaasAppDemo1\SaasAppDemo1\Data\SqlAzureDbHelper.cs:line 19
   at Inspinia_MVC5.Data.SqlAzureDbHelper.CreateDatabase(String companyName, String nit) in C:\Proyectos\SaasAppDemo1\Main\SaasAppDemo1\SaasAppDemo1\Data\SqlAzureDbHelper.cs:line 24
   at Inspinia_MVC5.Areas.GlobalAdmin.Controllers.EmpresasController.Create(Empresa empresa) in C:\Proyectos\SaasAppDemo1\Main\SaasAppDemo1\SaasAppDemo1\Areas\GlobalAdmin\Controllers\EmpresasController.cs:line 86
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: Are you executing this code in an Azure Website?

Comment: you should **NOT** use Web Edition of Azure SQL DB. It is depricated! It will be easier to create a DB by just connecting to the MASTER with your Administrator credentials and executing CREATE DDL statement (with your favorite SQL DB layer/ provider - ADO.NET, EF, etc...).

Comment: Yes I am executing this in an azure website, @astaykov good suggestion, but my code does not even get to that line. Your suggestion is also good, but if they developed an Azure Management SDK it should work too.

Comment: check this tutorial on how to store and load X.509 Cetificates in Azure Web Apps: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/ 
As for DB Editions - it may work today (when you load the certificate), but will certainly fail when this version (Web/Business edition) is finally retired. Actually I am not really sure if you can create a Web Edition SQL DB today - have to try that out using the management portal first.